# jsrender: nesting templates with {{each}}

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, jquery-templates, jsrender

I have this piece of code in my template:

```
{{each(i, service) package_services}}
                <tr>
                    <td class="mini2">${service.name}</td>
                    <td class="mini2 right">${service.price}</td>
                    <td class="mini2 right" >${service.duration}</td>
                    <td class="mini2 right" >${service.max_products}</td>
                    <td class=""><a href="#" rel="" class="remove_package_service tipsyn" title="Odstrani moderatorja"><img src="/media/icons/no_14.png" /></a></td>
                </tr>
{{/each}}
```

and I have this sub template defined too:

```
<script id="row_tmpl_package_service" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td class="mini2">${service.name}</td>
        <td class="mini2 right">${service.price}</td>
        <td class="mini2 right">${service.duration}</td>
        <td class="mini2 right">${service.max_products}</td>
        <td class=""><a href="#" rel="" class="remove_package_service tipsyn" title="Odstrani moderatorja"><img src="/media/icons/no_14.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

how can I use already predefined template so I won't have to repeat the code?

I tried

```
{{each package_services tmpl="#row_tmpl_package_service"}}
```

but of course it doesn;t work, since in template I use {{service.name}} and {{service.price}} so how cna I tell to the "each" statement, that I have an extra namespace?

Comment: your question is about `js-render` but your code suggests jQuery Templates as for the javascript type set as `x-jquery-tmpl`

Answer (score 0):

For that use the "tmpl" tag and not an attribute like:

```
{{each(i, service) package_services}}
    {{tmpl({'service': service}) "#row_tmpl_package_service"}}
{{/each}}
```

If this don't work in your configuration try to setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a example of your code =).

Comment: it doesn't work :(... and it is a little messy to seti it up in jsfiddle ... thanks for your answer... right now I am in a bit of hurry so I'll use the cloned code... but I will def. return to this and solve it!

Comment: Your templates don't seen to work with a recent version of jsrender, maybe it's due https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/41.